# Powershell Stored Procedure with User-defined type parameter

Tags: sql-server, powershell

My SQL Server stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcessAssessments 
    @assessmentIds AssessmentList READONLY,
    @failed BIT
AS
    UPDATE dbo.table
    SET IsProcessed = 1,
        dbo.ProcessFailed = @failed,
        dbo.ProcessDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE
        dbo.ID IN (SELECT AssessmentId FROM @assessmentIds)
GO
```

In Powershell: under global definition, I am declaring the `$connection`, and `ArrayList`.

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$connection.Open()
$processedAssessments.Add("1")
$processedAssessments.Add("2")
$processedAssessments.Add("3")
UpdateAssessments($processedAssessments, 0)
```

Inside of the Method, I'm converting the `ArrayList` to a `DataTable`, and supplying it as a parameter to my stored procedure.

```
function UpdateAssessments([System.Collections.ArrayList] $assessments,[bool] $failed) {
    $table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    $table.Columns.Add("AssessmentId", "System.String") | Out-Null

    foreach($assessmentId in $assessments) {
        $row = $table.NewRow()
        $row.AssessmentId = $assessmentId
        $table.Rows.Add($row)
    }

    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $command.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    $command.CommandText = "ProcessKySpecialAssessments"
    $command.Connection = $connection

    $command.Parameters.Add("@assessmentIds", $table)
    $command.Parameters.Add("@failed", $failed)

    $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

However, when I execute this, I get the following exception:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to data type int.
>   The data for table-valued parameter "@assessmentIds" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.
>   SQL Server error is: 245, state: 1

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have this:  $table.Columns.Add("AssessmentId", "System.String")   But your SQL table type appears to be int?  Maybe this needs to match the SQL data type

Comment: Also I think you need to give the parameter an explicit type (structured), but I'll confess I know that from C#, I've never tried it from Powershell.

Comment: As an aside:Please avoid pseudo method syntax: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like _shell commands_ (no parentheses, whitespace-separated arguments), not like _methods_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading [this post](https://sqlserverpowershell.com/2014/01/16/pass-a-table-type-parameter-to-sql-server-via-powershell/), I altered the `SqlParameters`, and I was able to get it to work.

```
$command.Connection = $connection
    $command.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    $command.CommandText = "ProcessKySpecialAssessments"

    $assessmentIdsParam = New-Object('system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter')
    $failedParam = New-Object('system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter')

    $assessmentIdsParam.ParameterName = "assessmentIds"
    $assessmentIdsParam.SqlDBtype = [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Structured
    $assessmentIdsParam.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
    $assessmentIdsParam.value = $table

    $failedParam.ParameterName = "failed"
    $failedParam.SqlDBtype = [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Bit
    $failedParam.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
    $failedParam.value = $failed

    $command.parameters.add($assessmentIdsParam);
    $command.parameters.add($failedParam);

    $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```