# Update SQL table using PowerShell hash table without a foreach loop

Tags: sql-server, powershell

MSSQL lets you do a multi-row `UPDATE` and `INSERT` from some source, like another table, or JSON & XML data, etc.  Psuedo-example:

`INSERT INTO TBL SELECT * FROM SOURCE`

Is it possible to use a PowerShell hash table as the source?

```
  #psuedo code

$carHashTable = [pscustomobject]@{

    color = 'red'
    make = 'geo'
    model = 'metro'
    year = 1996
    insured = 0
}


#here-string
$sql = @"

    insert into
        SomeDumbTable
    select
        *
    from $carHashTable

"@

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sql
```

All the examples I've seen online use a `foreach` loop to do the actual insert or update.  *Bossmang* says loops (in SQL proper) are bad.

The only other option I can think of is using PowerShell to create a temp table in SQL, then use the temp  table as the source to do the the multi-insert.

Comment: From a PowerShell prompt have you tried `Import-Module SqlServer` and `Get-Help Write-SqlTableData -Full`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Stored Procedure with User-defined type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989137/powershell-stored-procedure-with-user-defined-type-parameter) Use a table-valued parameter, which is almost the same as a table variable. Note that that post doesn't mention you also need to supply `$param.TypeName`

Comment: The option to `write-SqlTableData` is AMAZAING; unfortunately though, it does not support `#temp` tables. I want to do this without using a Stored Procedure; however, it is an option, and that article helps.  I even tried `SqlBulkCopy` but that didn't work, either `$bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tempdb..#Test187"`.  "Loops are bad" in SQL, but not in PowerShell, I guess?  I'm going to have to do a `foreach` with an `update` per record.  It doesn't seem like PowerShell has a SQL `update` cmdlet yet, or the option to convert objects into DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to answer my own question.  If I make an incorrect statement, please correct me.

**1)**  YES.  You can convert a hash table [using this module created by James Brundage](https://github.com/StartAutomating/Pipeworks/blob/master/ConvertTo-DataTable.ps1) into an object that the `SqlServer` module can deal with.

```
#import module that converts PSObjects into a DataTable that SQL can handle (external author)
import-module -name C:\PowerShell\ConvertTo-DataTable.ps1 -Verbose

#import the csv, and convert it to a DataTable
$Jobs = import-csv -Path $Repository\$File -Delimiter '|' | ConvertTo-DataTable
```

**2)**  For the larger question, can you `UPDATE` without a `foreach` loop?, I'm going to say **NO**, at least not with a SQL `#temp` table, which was my original intention.  Here's what I've observed:

- `Write-SqlTableData` does not appear to support `#temp` tables
- `Write-SqlTableData`  DOES allow me to use the converted PS `$object`
  to write data; however, it only appends data to tables; I don't know
  of a way to UPDATE on some key
- The only way I was able to achieve this was by gleaning a lot on
  StackOverflow, and bringing in the SQL .NET client libraries
  `System.Data.SqlClient`.
- Those libraries allowed me to open and maintain a session with SQL so that I could create a `#temp` table, bulk copy content into it, then finally `UPDATE`ing the real target table.
- The `SqlServer` Modules for PowerShell seems to immediately open and close the session, so any `#temp` tables created *there* are only avilable to *that* session
- The session created by the .NET client libraries can be opened and maintained to run multiple queries, but it's separate from sessions created by the `SqlServer` modules -- PS can't gain access to `#temp` tables created in .Net sessions, and vice versa.